# Get type of asset publisher Liferay

Tags: types, liferay-6, assets

I need to get the type of the current asset publisher.
I have many portlets with asset publisher.
I am using Liferay 6.2 ce ga2

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution ( a bit tricky ) is to get the last article published and get its StructureId and then compare it to all ids of structure so as you get the name of structure, like this :

```
long classPk = assetEntry.getClassPK();
List<DDMStructure> structures =null;
String portletType="";


JournalArticle article = null;
try {
    article = JournalArticleLocalServiceUtil.getLatestArticle(classPk);
    String structureId = article.getStructureId();

structures = DDMStructureLocalServiceUtil.getStructures(groupId);

for (DDMStructure structureL : structures) {
    if(String.valueOf(structureL.getStructureId()).equals(structureId)){
        portletType = extractStructureName(structureL.getName());
        break;
    }
}
```